# John, Bob and Mary need to share 7 apples. How many ways can they do that, if John and Bob need to get at least 1 apple, and Mary at least 2?

Tags: combinatorics

When I looked at this problem, my first instinct was to immediately take away these 4 apples, and see how I can sort the remaining 3, but it hasn't led me to the correct solution.

Apples are identical

Comment: Did you allow for no apples after you take away the 4? Also, are apples identical?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After you give away the $1$, $1$, and $2$ apples, the remaining can be divided as $(3,0,0)$, $(2,1,0)$, $(2,0,1)$, $(1,2,0)$, $(1,1,1)$, $(1,0,2)$, $(0,3,0)$, $(0,2,1)$, $(0,1,2)$, $(0,0,3)$

Answer (score 2):

You have the right idea. Just need to find the number of nonnegative integer solutions to 
$$a+b+c = 3$$
Lookup [stars and bars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics))
specifically [theorem 2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics)#Theorem_two_2).

Answer (score 1):

Just distribute the extra 3.

To $1$ person $3$ ways

To $2$ people $6$ ways

To all $3$ people $1$ way

Total $10$ ways.